# change tornado cookie secret while running

Tags: python, cookies, server, tornado

I need to change tornado cookie secret while its running.
all the sample's define the secret code before start tornado server and I want to change cookie secret while my server running because I want to my server ignore all the cookie data saved before (expire cookie not do the job) and save new one's

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `RequestHandler` class has a copy of the main settings under `self.application.settings`.

You can modify the settings before setting the cookies:

```py
class MyHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def change_cookie_secret(self):
        self.application.settings['cookie_secret'] = '<new secret>'
```

Call `self.change_cookie_secret()` method before you create cookies.